# How to load event calendar in partial?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, partial-views

I am working on [event_calendar](https://github.com/elevation/event_calendar) plugin. I want to load event calendar in partial. I created method in controller and it will call to partial. But I do not know how to load calendar in partial. What should I add in partial? I am working on rails 2.3.8 and ruby 1.8.7

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I also used `event_calendar` and i just right following in my application and it works for me.

```
<%= event_calendar %>
```

Note:- I also faced some problem while using it earlier but then i create fields start_at, end_at and it works fine for me.

Comment: I18n::ArgumentError in Events#find

Object must be a Date, DateTime or Time object. nil given.                                                                I got this exception when I add your   code...I created fields start_at and end_at..

Answer (score 2):

put this in the controller:

```
@month = (params[:month] || (Time.zone || Time).now.month).to_i
@year = (params[:year] || (Time.zone || Time).now.year).to_i

@shown_month = Date.civil(@year, @month)

@event_strips = Event.event_strips_for_month(@shown_month)
```